# Python How to serialize dictionaries with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that will make a bank account that I can save onto a file and that call that file as needed. My function to making the account goes up to the stamping of the date of the creation of the account then goes blank. I know it doesn't go further than that because it doesn't create the file I want. Any advice or tips would be appreciated. Thanks all.

```
import os
import pickle
import datetime

clear = lambda: os.system("cls")
now = datetime.datetime
temp = 1

class Account:
    def __init__(self , account_number , account_balance , account_creation , account_firstname , account_lastname):
        self.acc_number = account_number
        self.acc_balance = account_balance
        self.acc_creation = account_creation
        self.acc_firstname = account_firstname
        self.acc_lastname = account_lastname

def account_creation(temp):
    acc = {}
    acc["account_firstname"] = input("Please enter the first name of the account")
    acc["account_lastname"] = input("Please enter the last name of the account")
    acc["account_balance"] = float(input("Please enter the balance of the account"))
    acc["account_creation"] = now
    account_exist = pickle.load(open("save.p" , "rb"))
    while True:
        if (temp in account_exist):
            temp = temp + 1
            continue
        else:
            account_exist.append(temp)
            acc["account_number"] = temp
            break
    d = Account(**account_creation())
    pickle.dump(d.Account , open("%d.p" % (temp) , "wb" ))
    print("account created")


account_creation(temp)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here: `d = Account(**account_creation())` ?

Comment: And in the next line, what is `d.Account` ?

Comment: I am creating an object that has the account's values, d is just a placeholder for the object.

Comment: `open("%d.p" , "wb" %(temp))` this has `"wb" % (temp)`, not `"%d.p" % (temp)`

Comment: Fixed that but now my code runs in an infinite loop.